# In OpenShift 3, how to run a docker image that requires root?

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-3

In OpenShift 3, how can deploy a docker image that requires root?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on devops SE

Answer (score 0):

You can run `oc edit scc restricted` and edit `runAsUser.Type` from `MustRunAsNonRoot` to `RunAsAny`. This is not recommended for security reasons.

Comment: It gives: Error from server (Forbidden): User "xxxx" cannot get securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope: User "xxxx" cannot get securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope (get securitycontextconstraints root)

Comment: Adjusting security settings of the cluster requires cluster admin access.

Comment: You can login to oc tools prior by `oc login -u system:admin -n default` and then management commands work

Answer (score 0):

Easier command to grant containers in specific project to run as any UID, including root, is:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default -n myproject
```

This would need to be run as a cluster admin. A normal user, or even a project admin, cannot run this command.

If using OpenShift Online you will not be able to do this.

Comment: It gives: Error from server (Forbidden): User "xxxx" cannot get securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope: User "xxxx" cannot get securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope (get securitycontextconstraints root)

Comment: I did say it had to be run as cluster admin. If you don't have full control of the cluster you cannot do it. Now perhaps indicate why you need it. What is the image you are trying to run and why does it require root? Images built to best practices would not need to run as root. Unfortunately a lot of images out there on Docker Hub aren't built with good security practices.

Comment: I have tested some docker images from the hub, and all require root privilegies. The last one was owncloud.

Comment: How can I be cluster admin on my account?

Comment: What OpenShift cluster are you using?

Comment: You can login to oc tools prior by `oc login -u system:admin -n default` and then management commands work, without `User "xxxx" cannot get securitycontextconstraints` error messages